# wildcard into .properties

Tags: java, properties

Does exist any method in witch i can add a wildcard into a properties file, and have the meaning of everything, like `a.b.*.c.d=lalalala`, or set a regex for all that ends in `a.b.c=anything`?

Answer (score 3):

A normal Java properties file doesn't handle this, no. Bear in mind that it's a hashtable really, usually mapping strings to strings.

It sounds like you probably want to create your own class for this - but perhaps you could use a `Properties` object as a simple way of inserting the data?