# String value from properties file

Tags: java, properties

I have a properties (cant change this file) and it looks like:

```
aaa.bbb.ccc.first=my first value
aaa.bbb.ccc.second=my second value
aaa.bbb.ccc.third=my third value
```

If I need any value in java classes I use `i18n.getText("aaa.bbb.ccc.first")` but it works only for single value.

Problem is because I dont know:

-value's names

-how many values are in aaa.bbb.ccc.~

How is it possible to get list of value aaa.bbb.ccc~?

Comment: FYI: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328999/wildcard-into-properties

Comment: so there is no way to solve my problem?

Comment: `aaa.bbb.ccc=firts, second, third` then `String str = i18n.getText("aaa.bbb.ccc");` Then you do some `String.split` to separate your list.

Comment: I can not change properties file, have to do it only in java

Comment: You can always do `Collection<String> propNames = properties.stringPropertyNames().stream().filter(k -> k.startsWith("aaa.bbb.ccc.")).collect(Collectors.toSet());`, but as others have pointed out, a property file is not a good way to provide data that has a grouped structure.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [MapFilter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13531687/823393). Use the `MapFilter(Properties p, String prefix)` constructor.

```
public void test() {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("aaa.bbb.ccc.first", "my first value");
    props.put("aaa.bbb.ccc.second", "my second value");
    props.put("aaa.bbb.ccc.third", "my third value");
    props.put("Other.props", "others");
    MapFilter<String> filtered = new MapFilter(props, "aaa.bbb.ccc.");
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> e : filtered.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println("Key: " + e.getKey() + " Value: " + e.getValue());
    }
    System.out.println(filtered);

}
```

Comment: properties file could be change in every moment, just know that values are in `aaa.bbb.ccc.`

Answer (score 0):

Hash maps are not meant for the kind of lookup you want to do: [Tries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) and [radix trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree) are. There is an implementation of the Patricia trie data structure (i.e., binary radix trees) in [Apache Commons Collections](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/): Just create a trie from your `Map<String, Whatever>` (you have a nice constructor at the purpose) and with `prefixMap("aaa.bbb.ccc")` you obtain the submap of all the entries whose key have that prefix.

Answer (score 0):

Properties has a method propertyNames(). You can use that to get all the keys then do whatever you want from there.

Comment: This is not wrong, but it is far from a complete answer.

Comment: I as trying to lead him in the right direction without writing all the code for him :)